# How do I test an "error" in Visual Studio Test Project

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to using test projects in VS, and am using VS 2012.  Lets say I have a WCF service that performs a read on a database and returns an object with a status code (something numeric) and a status message ("Success" or "Danger Will Robinson").

As part of a unit test, wouldn't I want the ability to test that these error codes and messages return appropriately?  If so, how would I go about testing for these exception circumstances?

Comment: Great answers everyone, thanks!  So my only issue is... what if the service I have doesn't accept any parameters.  My services is as simple as "GetUserNames()", which just returns a list of data.  I'm talking, this is the most simple service one could create.. I'm trying to think of a way that I can keep the service simple without having to "add" functionality just for unit testing.. know what I mean?

Comment: If you need to add functionality "just" for unit testing, perhaps this functionality belonged there all along. Is this additional functionality to throw an exception when something goes wrong? If so, wouldn't you want to be doing that in your production environment should the thing you're testing for go astray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of errors that you want to test. Those returned as part of a result and those that occur as exceptions. You could test the first type like:

```
[UnitTest]
public void MethodUnderTest_ScenarioBeingTested_ResultOfTest()
{
    // Arrange
    string expectedError = "Danger Will Robinson";
    IMySpecialService service = new FakeSpecialService();

    // Act
    var result = service.CallOperation(thisArgumentCausesError);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedError, result.ReturnMessage);
}
```

The above will test an error message returned from some fictive object and will be compared against an expected error message "Danger Will Robinson";

When you want to test exceptions you use similar approach but decorate your unit test class with a special attribute:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(System.DivideByZeroException))]
[UnitTest]
public void MethodUnderTest_ScenarioBeingTested_ExpectedResult()
{
    // Arrange
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    IMathService service = new FakeService();

    // Act
    decimal result = service.PerformDivision(i, j);

    // Assert
    // This part is never reached because Assertion is handled by ExpectedException
}
```

In this case you know that an exception will be raised and which will not be handled. Here we are testing some fictive service that performs some math operations, like division.

This should give you an idea how to approach your unit tests.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the assistance.  In the end, I was able to follow this model and provide several tests to validate the success and failure methodology.